# is not checked out... bundle install does NOT fix help!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems

```
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
```

So what do I do? bundle install works on development, but when I push and deploy to my production server. I get this error, even after running bundle install on my production server.

Comment: Even if your question is already solved, could you add some more context to it so it will be useful for other people having similar problems? What did you do to get this error message, for example?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You're probably running Passenger. This is the issue with some solutions - http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=505

Try running `bundle install --deployment`

Comment: Just a note, got a depreciation message running 3.0.9 stating that we should use bundle install path deployment.

Comment: That masks the problem more than solves it – --deployment mode is not intended for development and poses problems with each bundle.

Comment: I had the same problem with Pow and this fixed it too.

Comment: +1. Saved my day a few times. Interesting that I have to install bundles with --no-deployment, and then again with --deployment for Redmine.

Comment: "In deployment mode, Bundler will ´roll-out´ the bundle for production use." This vendors (copies) the gems into your development app, bloating the app's code. There must be a better way to solve the issue?

Comment: [*Regarding my previous comment:*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648870/is-not-checked-out-bundle-install-does-not-fix-help#comment45219008_6648894) Try removing `Gemfile.lock` and `.bundle/config` from your project and running `bundle install`. (Note that the lack of a `Gemfile.lock` may cause some gems to update when you run `bundle install`.) It fixed the issue for me. Worth a try before you enable deployment mode in development or test environments.

Comment: In case you guys need it later, this is how you revert it:

`bundle install --no-deployment`

Comment: The `--deployment` in now deprecated, it is now best to use `bundle config set --local deployment 'true'`

Answer (score 24):

This error can be related to the spring gem. Regenerating spring binstubs worked for me.

`bundle exec spring binstub --all`

https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/387

Answer (score 14):

for the guys that stuck with "bundle & git repo " problems.

```bash
bundle pack
bundle install --path vendor/cache
```

more details, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5268534/445908

Answer (score 6):

For me it was just a matter of adding this to gemfile:

```
source 'http://gems.github.com'
```

Comment: Note that this solution won't work now because GitHub no longer builds gems. See http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:fAsVmK28OwwJ:gems.github.com

Answer (score 6):

When your computer never restarts, Spring might be the problem. Spring was running for 350 hours and caused caching the outdated TEST environment. I had this problem in my cucumber test environment in Rubymine. Strange this was that from (mac) the command prompt there was no problem.

```
spring status
spring stop
```

and voila! It all worked again.

Comment: This can also happen if you change your repo urls from git:// to https://. `spring stop` a.k.a. "have you tried turning it off and on again?" is the only (!) thing that will work in that case.

Answer (score 6):

Ran into this problem after upgrading to ruby 2.7.0

Looks like maybe there has been changes to deprecate the use of the business company focused`:github =>` to the actual software platform focused `:git =>`. Maybe better for easier code logic maintainability.

Change the following:

```
gem 'devise', :github => 'plataformatec/devise'
```

to the following:

```
gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise'
```

An alternative is you may still reference :github as your git_source at the top of your Gemfile and just reference to the Gems as normal like so:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'                                                                                                                             
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
...
gem 'devise'
```

Comment: This was the solution to my problem after upgrading too. Upvoted :)

Comment: That fixed it for me as well. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If you run `bundle install` and then on attempt to run anything you see "... github.com ... is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first."
- that means you need to use `bundle exec` before your command, e.g.:

```
bundle exec rails s
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone here in 2021, the accepted answer is outdated as `--deployment` flag is deprecated.

Use this instead:

```
bundle config set --local deployment 'true'
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing gem locally in project directory fix it for me.

```
 $ bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution

```
$ bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

has fixed my issue with running multiple rails app via foreman.

Note: Don't forget to execute `rbenv rehash` after if you are using `rbenv`.

And add `/vendor/bundle` in your `.gitignore` if not yet added.

Comment: Bundle is recommending to use `bundle config set --local path 'vendor/bundle'` instead as `--path` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that i had no access to github

try `ssh -vT git@github.com` and see if you get

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Then see https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, that helped me when I was getting same issue while installing private gem from my Github repo, in Docker (my gems are in volume /gems):

```
# Add known host 
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN bundle config set path /gems # this fixes issue with private repos DON'T USE ENV BUNDLE_PATH /gems
RUN --mount=type=ssh bundle install
```

To forward SSH, build using this command:

```
docker build --ssh default .
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission error. The following worked

**Environment** : RVM with Apache

**RVM user:group** : rvm:rvm

**Apache user:group** : apache:apache

You need to add apache user to RVM group

```
usermod -a -G rvm apache
```

Comment: Also adding to the discussion: I was having the same problems, so I tried explicitly setting the user in nginx.conf to the user for which RVM was installed and it worked. So before it was commented out: #user nobody;, now it's: user jake.

Answer (score 0):

What finally helped me once and forever:

1. Reinstalling everything as Galen suggested (all the steps from https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md)
2. Using `bundle` instead of `rvmsudo bundle`

Answer (score 0):

Update your Gemfile as follows;

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin/active_admin', branch: '0-6-stable'
```

and then,

```
bundle install
```

Iif still error occurs (because of you have tried '**bundle install --deployment**', then try running)

```
bundle install --no-deployment
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting bash session helped for me

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got the error message on Circle CI:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
bundle exec rails db:setup

https://github.com/randym/axlsx.git (at c8ac844@c8ac844) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

This error happened when **gem dependencies can not be resolved**.
So I switched back to pre release version in my Gemfile to fix it

```
-gem 'axlsx', github: 'randym/axlsx', ref: 'c8ac844572b25fda358cc01d2104720c4c42f450'
+gem 'axlsx', '3.0.0.pre'
```

and run update to update the gem dependencies

```bash
bundle update axlsx
```