# cron job fails with "is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler

I seem to have a similar problem as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648870/is-not-checked-out-bundle-install-does-not-fix-help), where Bundler complains of a gem not being checked out. However, mine shows an error when running a rake task using a cron job. (Otherwise, the site seems to deploy fine in production using Phusion Passenger, and the rake task runs when called in the command line )

The error is:
   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/source.rb:571:in `load_spec_files': git://github.com/moneill/Google-Maps-for-Rails.git (at modified_markers) is not checked out. Please run`bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)

I tried using `bundle install --deployment`  ; `bundle pack` followed by `bundle install --path vendor/cache`.

One thing I haven't tried is to locally compile the git project and install the gem in the `vendor/bundle` folder. I am not using RVM for this particular server.

The cron job command is  `cd /home/[dir]/[rails_app_folder]/ && RAILS_ENV=production  /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rake [task] --trace`

Thank you!