# RoR rake bundle dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake, bundle

Platform: windows 7, running on JRuby 1.6.8.

```
C:\project> rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2.
Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

OK. I have added

```
gem "rake", "= 0.9.2.2"
```

to Gemfile and ran:

```
C:\project> bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

<polite>WTF?</polite>

I have also done

```
bundle install --deployment
```

to no avail.

I have different versions of rake installed:

```
C:\project>gem list

LOCAL GEMS
...
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
```

How to resolve this? I need rake db:migrate working with my specific (inherited) RoR project with gems that tend to be slightly out of date, but they are all specified in Gemfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't run `bundle --deployment` until you clearly understand what it is used for.  (it's confusing, we usually use `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`)
2. The first error means, that you should execute your command with `bundle exec`, like  `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
3. after the version change in the `Gemfile` you should have just run `bundle install` without `--deployment`.

At this point I'd recommend to delete the `.bundle` folder in your project home, this reverses the `--deployment` call.  Afterwards call `bundle install` and try it again. If it doesn't work please let us know.

Don't get frustrated, bundle is pretty cool as soon as you get the hang of it.

Comment: that wasn't enough though: it appeared that newer activerecord version was a problem, I had to do what you wrote plus uninstall newer activerecord gem.

THANKS!!

Comment: And what if I had trouble with Passenger? According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648870/is-not-checked-out-bundle-install-does-not-fix-help) I should use --deployment. But after I've used it - I have error with "You have already activated rake 10.0.3". I even don't have this version in my gems list! But it apppears.

Comment: @TiSer sorry, i don't have enough information (the post you link is almost two years old). Try to create a new question and specify more details.