# ROR bundle install : git://github.com/Goin/dm-migrations.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle

I have an existing ROR application I've inherited.  I needed to add a GEM file to the Gemfiles list.  I then ran a "bundle install".  Apache (/phusion/rack) now shows the error "git://github.com/Goin/dm-migrations.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)".  According to bundle this gem is installed however: "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bundler/gems/dm-migrations-3d190029bb8c".

What is the root cause of the problem and the fix?

TY,
Fred

Comment: Did you try to install the gem manually like using `gem install` command before using `bundle install`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is not checked out... bundle install does NOT fix help!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648870/is-not-checked-out-bundle-install-does-not-fix-help)