# snorby web application error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For the past few hours, I have been working on installing snorby on ubuntu 12.04 64bit.
snorby with Rails server works just fine, but whenever I want to use Passenger and Apache2, I get the following error messsage in the browser:

```
Web application could not be started

It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:

bundle install

If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:

Is this app supposed to be run as the nobody user?
Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.
Please check whether the correct RVM gemset is being used.
Sometimes, RVM gemsets may be broken. Try resetting them.
```

Full spec:

```
install with rvm, ruby 1.9.3 ,gems 2.2.2, rails 4 ,passenger 4.0.37.
```

Full Passenger log:

```
-------- The exception is as follows: -------
https://github.com/Snorby/delayed_job_data_mapper.git (at master) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first. (Bundler::GitError)

/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:179:in `rescue in load_spec_files'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:176:in `load_spec_files'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:86:in `local_specs'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:150:in `specs'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:53:in `__materialize__'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `setup'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:245:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:348:in `running_bundler'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:243:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Application root: `/var/www/snorby`

Environment (value of `$RAILS_ENV`, `$RACK_ENV`, `$WSGI_ENV` and `$PASSENGER_ENV`): `production`

Ruby interpreter command: `/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/wrappers/ruby`

User and groups:

```
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
```

Environment variables:

```
APACHE_PID_FILE = /var/run/apache2.pid
GEM_HOME = /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545
SHELL = /bin/sh
APACHE_RUN_USER = www-data
IRBRC = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/.irbrc
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXX80xOPD
MY_RUBY_HOME = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545
SERVER_PORT = 80
USER = nobody
DOCUMENT_ROOT = /var/www/snorby/public
REQUEST_URI = /
IN_PASSENGER = 1
RACK_ENV = production
REMOTE_PORT = 53485
APACHE_LOG_DIR = /var/log/apache2
PATH = /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
WSGI_ENV = production
SERVER_ADMIN = admin@localhost
PWD = /var/www/snorby
APACHE_RUN_GROUP = www-data
LANG = C
NODE_PATH = /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/node_lib
NODE_ENV = production
REMOTE_ADDR = 127.0.0.1
SHLVL = 0
SERVER_NAME = 127.0.0.1
HOME = /nonexistent
RAILS_ENV = production
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
LOGNAME = nobody
QUERY_STRING =
GEM_PATH = /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global
SERVER_ADDR = 127.0.0.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production
APACHE_LOCK_DIR = /var/lock/apache2
APACHE_RUN_DIR = /var/run/apache2
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
_ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH = /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global
```

Ulimits:

```
Unknown
```

System memory usage:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           986        877        108          0         25        326
-/+ buffers/cache:        525        460
Swap:         1021        177        844
```

General Ruby interpreter information:

```
RUBY_VERSION = 1.9.3
RUBY_PLATFORM = x86_64-linux
RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
RubyGems version = 2.2.2
```

Ruby configuration (`RbConfig::CONFIG`):

```
DESTDIR =
MAJOR = 1
MINOR = 9
TEENY = 1
PATCHLEVEL = 545
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
EXEEXT =
prefix = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545
ruby_install_name = ruby
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME = ruby
RUBY_SO_NAME = ruby
exec = exec
ruby_pc = ruby-1.9.pc
PACKAGE = ruby
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =  newline.c
USE_RUBYGEMS = YES
MANTYPE = doc
NROFF = /usr/bin/nroff
vendorhdrdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/include/ruby-1.9.1/vendor_ruby
sitehdrdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/include/ruby-1.9.1/site_ruby
rubyhdrdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/include/ruby-1.9.1
UNIVERSAL_INTS =
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES =
configure_args =  '--prefix=/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545' '--disable-install-doc' '--enable-shared'
vendordir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
sitedir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby
ruby_version = 1.9.1
sitearch = x86_64-linux
arch = x86_64-linux
RI_BASE_NAME = ri
ridir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/ri
rubylibprefix = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby
MAKEFILES = Makefile
PLATFORM_DIR =
THREAD_MODEL = pthread
SYMBOL_PREFIX =
EXPORT_PREFIX =
COMMON_HEADERS =
COMMON_MACROS =
COMMON_LIBS =
MAINLIBS =
ENABLE_SHARED = yes
DLDLIBS =  -lc
SOLIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED = -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib -L/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib -lruby
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib -L/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib -lruby-static
LIBRUBYARG = -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib -L/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib -lruby
LIBRUBY = libruby.so.1.9.1
LIBRUBY_ALIASES = libruby.so.1.9 libruby.so
LIBRUBY_SO = libruby.so.1.9.1
LIBRUBY_A = libruby-static.a
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME =
rubyw_install_name =
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.1.9
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED = gcc -shared
EXTDLDFLAGS =
warnflags = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
debugflags = -ggdb
optflags = -O3
cxxflags =  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
cflags =  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
cppflags =
NULLCMD = :
INSTALLDOC = nodoc
CAPITARGET = nodoc
RDOCTARGET = nodoc
EXECUTABLE_EXTS =
ARCHFILE =
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE = no
EXTOUT = .ext
PREP = miniruby
TEST_RUNNABLE = yes
setup = Setup
EXTSTATIC =
STRIP = strip -S -x
TRY_LINK =
LIBPATHENV = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RPATHFLAG =  -Wl,-R%1$-s
LIBPATHFLAG =  -L%1$-s
LINK_SO =
LIBEXT = a
DLEXT2 =
DLEXT = so
LDSHAREDXX = g++ -shared
LDSHARED = gcc -shared
CCDLFLAGS = -fPIC
STATIC =
ARCH_FLAG =
DLDFLAGS =
ALLOCA =
codesign =
POSTLINK = :
WERRORFLAG = -Werror
CHDIR = cd -P
RMALL = rm -fr
RMDIRS = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
RMDIR = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
CP = cp
RM = rm -f
PKG_CONFIG = pkg-config
DOXYGEN =
DOT =
MAKEDIRS = /bin/mkdir -p
MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
INSTALL_DATA = /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
INSTALL_SCRIPT = /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROGRAM = /usr/bin/install -c
SET_MAKE =
LN_S = ln -s
NM = nm
DLLWRAP =
WINDRES =
OBJCOPY = :
OBJDUMP = objdump
ASFLAGS =
AS = as
AR = ar
RANLIB = ranlib
try_header =
COUTFLAG = -o
OUTFLAG = -o
CPPOUTFILE = -o conftest.i
GNU_LD = yes
GCC = yes
EGREP = /bin/grep -E
GREP = /bin/grep
CPP = gcc -E
CXXFLAGS =  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
CXX = g++
OBJEXT = o
CPPFLAGS =
LDFLAGS = -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic
CFLAGS =  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC
CC = gcc
target_os = linux
target_vendor = unknown
target_cpu = x86_64
target = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
host_os = linux-gnu
host_vendor = unknown
host_cpu = x86_64
host = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
RUBYW_BASE_NAME = rubyw
RUBY_BASE_NAME = ruby
build_os = linux-gnu
build_vendor = unknown
build_cpu = x86_64
build = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE = 2014-02-24
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION = 1.9.3
BASERUBY = echo executable host ruby is required.  use --with-baseruby option.; false
target_alias =
host_alias =
build_alias =
LIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm
ECHO_T =
ECHO_N = -n
ECHO_C =
DEFS =
mandir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/man
localedir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/locale
libdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib
psdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/doc/ruby
pdfdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/doc/ruby
dvidir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/doc/ruby
htmldir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/doc/ruby
infodir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/info
docdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share/doc/ruby
oldincludedir = /usr/include
includedir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/include
localstatedir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/var
sharedstatedir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/com
sysconfdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/etc
datadir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share
datarootdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/share
libexecdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/libexec
sbindir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/sbin
bindir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin
exec_prefix = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545
PACKAGE_URL =
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT =
PACKAGE_STRING =
PACKAGE_VERSION =
PACKAGE_TARNAME =
PACKAGE_NAME =
PATH_SEPARATOR = :
SHELL = /bin/bash
rubylibdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1
archdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
sitelibdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
sitearchdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
vendorlibdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
vendorarchdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
topdir = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
```

Activated Ruby gems:

```
bundler => 1.5.3
```

Ruby load path (`$LOAD_PATH`):

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
```

Ruby loaded libraries (`$LOADED_FEATURES`):

```
enumerator.so
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/compatibility.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/errors.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/platform.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/thread.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/etc.so
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/binary_compatibility.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/buildout/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/socket.so
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/socket.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpdir.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/native_support_utils.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/analytics_logger.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/constants.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/io/console.so
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/gem_path_manipulation.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/match_platform.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/version.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest.so
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/digest.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/set.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ftp.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/http.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/https.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldap.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldaps.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/mailto.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/request.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/core.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/cookie.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/util.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/uri_formatter.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/bn.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/cipher.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/config.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/digest.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/x509-internal.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/securerandom.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/resolv.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/text.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/name_tuple.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/path.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/git.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/strscan.so
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/index.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/endpoint_specification.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/ui.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Passenger is using a different version of Ruby and Gem. Can you go to `/var/www/snorby` and try running `bundle install`, and see what happens?

Comment: I did it, the installation goes perfect, aka no error are showing up. I tried to reload apache and nothing..

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well just now. Make sure that apache is running under a user account that has permissions with RVM. This is of course provided that your gem is actually installed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052159/191741