# rails best in place forces bundle install always

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I have a rails project and I started used best in place gem. In order to make it work i had to put this line as

gem 'best_in_place', github: 'bernat/best_in_place', branch: "rails-4"

in my Gemfile.

Now whenver I deploy the project I am forced to do a bundle install because if I dont I get a Phusion error saying that

git://github.com/bernat/best_in_place.git (at rails-4) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)

I also tried to bundle install --deployment and then symlink the vendor/bundle folder into my shared directory but that also does not solve the problem. I have the symlink after a fresh deployment but somehow it does not take. I have to do a bundle install every time i deploy.

Please help. This takes a good 20 minutes to deploy now as against the 3-4 minutes it used to take earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Just run:

```
bundle install --deployment
```

Ref:

1. http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=505
2. [is not checked out... bundle install does NOT fix help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648870/is-not-checked-out-bundle-install-does-not-fix-help)

Comment: Hi Rajesh - thank you for taking the time to answer this question. But this is what I am trying not to do. I can do a bundle install --deployment and that downloads and installs all the gems in the rails/current/vendor/bundle folder. But I have to do this every time i do a deployment. I am not able to symlink this folder.

Comment: This is primarily caused by the best_in_place gem that links to a github repository. And there is no way - seemingly - to use the same symlinked gems from the previous install. Therefore whenever I do a deploy it is forcing me to do a complete bundle install --deployment. Takes 20 minutes to deploy now as against 1 minute it used to take. I am leaning towards taking best_in_place out of the application and not use this gem anymore. The github dependency is killing me on deployment. -- Hope this helps.