# Rails gem git source not checked out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bundler, best-in-place

I was using the best_in_place gem on a project but decided it was not needed and removed it from the gemfile and the other references to it on my code.
Now everytime I run a rails command I got this error

> The git source https://github.com/aaronchi/best_in_place.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application

I dont even have this gem installed anymore, I created another gemset on rvm, reinstalled rails, reinstalled ruby, followed the steps on https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md

No success yet...

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but did you run `bundle install` as it says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following page may have what you're looking for. If so, we might need to mark this as a duplicate:

[is not checked out... bundle install does NOT fix help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648870/is-not-checked-out-bundle-install-does-not-fix-help)

Let me know if that's not the case.