# error Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

This Saturday (27th, December), I upgraded my project Rails version from version 4.1.5 to version 4.2.0. And I also upgraded the Ruby version from 2.1.2 to 2.1.5.

Today, I was trying to run a Controller generator: `bin/rails g controller Clients index` and I realized that the command is not working. I am getting this error:

```
Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources
```

I tried other commands like: `bin/rake db:migrate`, `bin/rake` and the same problem.

But I can run the server using: `bin/rails s`. I can navigate through the website too.

[image: My last commit changes...]

Comment: Did you bundle updated!!!

Comment: @RubyOnRails yes I did. I run "bin/bundle install" and "bin/bundle update"

Comment: When I run "bin/bundle install" I get this:



`MacBook-Pro-de-Patricio:erp_web psantos$ bin/bundle install 
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0`

Comment: I guess you have to install dependencies.. Can you send me output of "bin/bundle install --trace"

Comment: @RubyOnRails, here is the output:

`MacBook-Pro-de-Patricio:erp_web psantos$ bin/bundle install --trace
Unknown switches '--trace'`

Comment: try this in inside your app repository "bundle install --trace"

Comment: @RubyOnRails I am inside my application directory.

Comment: Posting a gigantic and unreadable screenshot really doesn't help your question.

Comment: @tadman, you can see it readable if you open in new tab. That was the best way I found to show the last changes made before having the problem. Anyway, the problem was solved. See my Answer to the post.

thanks

Comment: It's still largely a useless artifact for the purposes of answering this question. Try to post plain text whenever possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The problem was, I upgraded the Rails version but I did not upgrade the `bin/ folder`.

So, to do that, I had to run the following command, and override everything:

```
$ bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I try to run the command meant to fix it. :-/

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
bin/bundle install
```

Solves the problem ;)

Answer (score 4):

Earlier version was i18n --version 0.6.1

Issue got resolved using the below command.

```
sudo gem install i18n --version 0.7
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and solved it by deleting the `Gemfile.lock` and running another `bundle` command.

After that, I was back to an earlier version of i18n (0.6.11) and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you is using RVM you need reset your RVM gemsets, try this:

https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Resetting-RVM-gemsets

Answer (score 0):

I did all of the above without result. Then I discovered that i18n couldn't be installed because my Ruby version was too low. (Said message was lost in the blast that bundler emits.) I updated Ruby and voila! i18n installed. NB: for some reason, Gemfile.lock showed it as installed even before this success, but RubyMine didn't show it as one of the installed libraries. Go figure.