# Web application could not be started - Rails and CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, centos

This was working fine just a few hours ago and then all of a sudden started giving an error. Yes, it really is running ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.1.3 (It's an ancient legacy application from the dark ages). Using Apache 2.2.15

I have tried even so slightly updating my gemfile to use rails 1.9.3 and the corresponding gems for rails 3.1.4

bundle show activesupport shows the correct directory of activesupport.

More of the error:

```
Could not find activesupport-3.1.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `rescue in require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
  /srv/rails/quotes/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  /srv/rails/quotes/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  /srv/rails/quotes/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/passenger-4.0.8/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:82:in `eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/passenger-4.0.8/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:82:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/passenger-4.0.8/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:127:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/passenger-4.0.8/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:6:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/passenger-4.0.8/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:5:in `<main>'
Application root
```

Gemfile [unupdated version]

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'rake'

gem 'activesupport', '3.1.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', " ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', " ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

group :development do
    gem 'bullet'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.3.0'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
 
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem 'ruby-odbc'
gem 'exception_notification_rails3', :require=>'exception_notifier'
gem 'jquery_datepicker'
```

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.3)
      actionpack (= 3.1.3)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.3)
      activemodel (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.3)
    activemodel (3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.3)
      activemodel (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.1.7)
      activerecord (~> 3.1.0)
    activeresource (3.1.3)
      activemodel (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
    activesupport (3.1.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (2.2.3)
    builder (3.0.4)
    bullet (4.8.0)
      activesupport
      uniform_notifier (>= 1.4.0)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.1)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    exception_notification_rails3 (1.2.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    jquery-rails (2.3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery_datepicker (0.4)
    json (1.8.0)
    libv8 (3.11.8.17)
    mail (2.3.3)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.23)
    multi_json (1.7.7)
    paperclip (3.4.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.0)
      mime-types
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.3.10)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.3)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.3)
      actionpack (= 3.1.3)
      activerecord (= 3.1.3)
      activeresource (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.3)
    railties (3.1.3)
      actionpack (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ref (1.0.5)
    ruby-odbc (0.99995)
    sass (3.2.9)
    sass-rails (3.1.7)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    sprockets (2.0.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7)
    therubyracer (0.11.4)
      libv8 (~> 3.11.8.12)
      ref
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.7)
    treetop (1.4.14)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.1.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    uniform_notifier (1.4.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.4)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
  activesupport (= 3.1.3)
  bullet
  coffee-rails (~> 3.1.0)
  exception_notification_rails3
  execjs
  jquery-rails (= 2.3.0)
  jquery_datepicker
  paperclip
  rails (= 3.1.3)
  rake
  ruby-odbc
  sass-rails (~> 3.1.0)
  sqlite3
  therubyracer
  uglifier
  will_paginate
```

Comment: can you provide your Gemfile? what is the output of rvm current? have you tried bundle install?

Comment: @AndreasGebhard updated in the original post - the corresponding gemlock has all corresponding gems for rails 3.1.3

Comment: I wonder why ActiveSupport is explicitly named in Gemfile, shouldn't it be a depenency of rails? Anyhow, what does rvm current say? Is it the same as ruby -v?

Comment: Can you add in your Gemfile.lock. can you give us the ruby version it thinks it's running? Can you run "bundle install"?

Comment: The gemlock file is very long and boring, I am running ruby 1.9.2 with rails 3.1.3. I'll add a few of the top-level ones from gem.lock

Comment: @AndreasGebhard

I think something went awry with passenger, the production code says passenger isn't installed but the dev code says its fine. I can't publish with git, since its rigged to push all changes in dev to prod (which is not possible right now as we're upgrading many apps that are not ready). How would I reconfigure passenger for the prod env? I am not familiar with it and don't see it in the gemlock file

Comment: @Harry Sorry, but I never used Passenger, always stuck with unicorn. So I can't give any advice, sorry.

Comment: @AndreasGebhard - thanks for all your help - it was actually a bundler error but I got it resolved

Comment: @Harry glad to hear you solved the issue. And thanks fot the link.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how it happened but the application in production somehow got debundled if that's even a thing?

Updating the gemfile with much pain, along with running the commands outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007773/installing-gems-with-bundler-big-problem/5268534#5268534) resolved the issue